# Login in cake doesn't work

Tags: cakephp

I have a litle problem with my app in cakephp because i need to do a login page. I try to force it with a diferent css.

This is my default.php in view layouts.

```
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <?php
                                echo $this->Html->link('<p>Login</p>',
                                    array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login'),
                                    array('class' => 'parent', 'escape'=> false)
                                    );
                            ?>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

And i have this layout for login page.

```
<?php
  echo $this->Html->css('login');
?>
```

In route.php i have this:

```
Router::connect('/login', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
```

With all of this the login page Keep white page.

Can you help me please?

Comment: A white page _probably_ means a fatal error - none of the code in the question is relevant (except the route definition, but that's far from important). Open the url `/login` and check your application error logs to identify what's happening, until you can point at an error message *nobody can help you*.

Answer (score 0):

to set layout: you need to set the layout inside your login action in User controller

```
public function login(){
    $this->layout = 'login';
    ...
}

//in your login layout
echo $this->fetch('content');
```

this line is to set your css

```
echo $this->Html->css('login');
```

Even though I am not sure if you have created your login layout here: app/View/Layouts/login.ctp

Comment: did you fetch your content in login layout?

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite not descriptive.

But let me help you with what I can.

The best solution is to set your debug to 2.
White screen might be caused of the page have error but not shown..

Btw. Can you provide clear overview about your file actualy..

I notice that you said about default.ctp in view layout. But that one is the view or the layout? I assume you mean in app/view/layout/default.ctp. But in the layout, there is no code to fetch the content,and to set the css.

By right, in default.ctp, it should be your main layout..

```
<html>
<head>
   <?php echo $this->Html->css('login'); ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $this->fetch('content') ?>
</body>
</html>
```